# how to use "IN" in node-mysql

Tags: node-mysql

I want to do this:

```
var ids = '1,2,3';
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?)', ids, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].id);
});
```

Unfortunately it's not giving the correct results.

When tracing through node-mysql, I've discovered that the query was interpreted as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('1,2,3')
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Any ideas how I can make this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few seconds posting the question, I've figured it out.

```
var ids = [1,2,3];
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?)', ids, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].id);
});
```